# How to understand variable and variable's value in bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

list="one two three"
one=1
two=2 
three=3
for k in $list
do 
    echo $k
done
```

For the code above, output is:
one
two
three
But I always think it should output:
1
2
3
It's confusing. How to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion `$k` just gives you the name of the variable as a string. If you want the value of the variable, you must use the parameter expansion syntax `${!k}`. This is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

list="one two three"
one=1
two=2 
three=3
for k in $list
do 
        echo "${!k}"
done
```

#### Output

```
1
2
3
```